# How to change an image which has dimensions (512, 512, 3) to a tensor of size ([1, 3, 224, 224])

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I was trying to implement a paper where the input dimensions are meant to be a tensor of size ([1, 3, 224, 224]). My current image size is (512, 512, 3).

How do I resize and convert in order to input to the model?

Comment: Usually you do the resize during the preparing input data. Depending which framework you're using it can be set easily the size of input image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming image already converted to `torch.Tensor` and has shape `(512, 512, 3)`, one of possible ways:

```
from torchvision.transforms import Resize

image = image.permute((2, 0, 1))  # convert to (C, H, W) format

image = image.unsqueeze(0)  # add fake batch dimension

resize = Resize((224, 224))

new_image = resize(image)
```

Now `new_image.shape` equals to `(1, 3, 224, 224)`